# Advice for doing an entire exterior reno?

Tags: renovation

Need to renovate my exterior and looking for advice... We completed an entire gut reno of our high ranch home a year ago and also replaced the roof. We need to now fix up the outside which means the following: replacing the siding, replacing the gutters, redoing the front steps of the house as the stones are falling apart, and regarding the backyard as its pitched towards the house. I figured since everything is going to be torn apart, I should also update the front yard landscaping as there is a slope from the front going down to the sidewalk so I want to create a retaining wall for part of the landscaping and have a more even area for the plants in front of the house.   If we want to get all of this done at once, should we use a general contractor who will most likely use a sub-contractor for the things he can't do or should I hire individual specialists (siding, landscaping, brick and mortar, etc..) If so, what order should the work be done? I assume siding first, then gutters then steps and landscaping? Any advice or insights based on your experience is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would do the hardscaping first, so any potential damage to the siding will be replaced with the new siding. This will get your grade pitched away from the house to keep mud at a minimum. Downspout leads for the gutters can be redone at this point too. Temporarily running the old downspouts into the new drains. Brickwork can be done too, that way anything that goes up against the house can be built properly. If the old siding is in the way, remove the area that is, and set the proper barrier, to the sheathing, and when the masonry is done, run the siding around the brick, so it is not trapped between a product that holds moisture and can lead to premature rot. Then the siding before the landscaping so any trash, nails etc can be cleaned up from the dirt, and the plantings won't be trampled. Paint too. Landscaping last.

Answer (score 0):

If you hire a General Contractor they will be responsible to schedule all the subcontractors, arrange and schedule the work, and be responsible for getting the work done to the standards outlined in the contract.  (Be sure to get a contract that provides this as well as a draw schedule.)  You will be paying more, but the GC is doing all the (Sometimes crazy) work that you will not have to do.

If you decide to hire individual trades, you will have the scheduling headaches as well as quality control work. You will have to have some knowledge of what order things should be happening and what or when those can be changed. You are going to need to be there more often to be sure the trades people understand the work that you want. You could be the ball in a game of ping-pong blame if something doesn't go right.  BUT...you save some money.

The choice is yours.